# What are the main axis of research in Chemistry?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

I would like to know what are the main problems currently studied in Chemistry.

For some reason, it seems that there is far less vulgarisation in chemistry than the other fields, and it's hard to find an overview of the field accessible to a layman (compared to math or physics for instance).

I only found this wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_chemistry), but I have no idea how relevant it is.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. This question sounds like you are asking for a big list of things, which is generally discouraged since there is unlikely to be a single correct answer. Check out the [faq] for more info.

Comment: That being said, the question is a fantastically interesting one in the philosophy of chemistry, and I do not believe that Wikipedia page captures the most important unsolved problems in chemistry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even though I voted to close this question as not constructive, these are among the most important unsolved problems in chemistry:

1. Liquid Water - We still know so little about the molecular level interactions of water molecules with themselves and other species. The great extent of [hydrogen bonding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_bond) networks in liquid water make it hard to model. Just how [many water molecules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_cluster) are solvating a proton in acid? Why are organic reactions between hydrophobic molecules [accelerated in the presence of water](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_water_reactions)?
2. Molecular origins of life, **especially homochirality**. The [formose reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_bond) is believed to be the origin of carbohydrates. Amino acids, lipids, and nucleic acids have similar hypothetical origins. However, how did these molecules come together [to create living organisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abiogenesis)? Why are most (not all) biomolecules present as one [enantiomer and not the other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homochirality)?
3. Protein folding. Can we predict the three-dimensional shape of a protein simply from the [order of the amino acids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_folding)? If so, then we could design proteins to do whatever we wanted.
4. True designer proteins. Once we solve the folding problem, then we can design proteins with active sites of specific geometries and specific amino acids in those active sites to do [whatever reaction we need](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_design).
5. High Temperature superconductors. Although [room temperature superconductors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room-temperature_superconductor) would be nice, inexpensive superconductors that operate at liquid nitrogen temperature (77 K) instead of liquid helium (5 K) temperatures would make NMR, MRI, and a host of other important techniques much cheaper.
6. The Energy Crisis. We need a chemical solution to replace fossil fuels as the world's primary energy source. [Hydrogen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_economy), [fuel cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_cell), [biomass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biomass), and [solar power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cell) all have serious drawbacks currently.
7. Replacement of petrochemical feedstocks. The petroleum industry remains the primary source of organic compounds. What will we do when the petroleum runs out?
8. Bonding theory. Modern bonding theories have developed into bloated mathematical formalisms that have removed any resemblance of intuition from the study of the structure of molecules. Can a unified modern bonding theory be developed that retains only the best features of [valence bond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_bond_theory) and [molecular orbital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital_theory) theories?
9. Improved ideality and efficiency of synthesis. Can the synthesis of compounds be improved so as to remove wasteful steps (like adding and removing protecting groups) or complex purifications to better adhere to the principles of [Green Chemistry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_chemistry)?
10. Structure-Property Relationship. All established relations between structure and activity is empirical, especially when the desired activity is biochemical. Can we design the best drug with the fewest side effects on the first try?

I find some of the [unsolved problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_chemistry) on the to be too narrow (stability of norbonyl cation - this is a subset of the structure-activity problem) or trivial (origin of rotation barrier in ethane - the problem is important but the answer is useless).

Comment: I would like to read about chemists' approaches to problem 8: making a unified modern bonding theory that retains the scope of VB and MO theory but still has intuition.  Where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

Chemistry is the study of the transformation of matter. People are studying every single aspect of how this happens.

You can't get a simple answer for this question.  For example, if you were to ask, "what are the important aspects of chemistry research?"  You might get back drug design, nanotechnology, etc. etc.  But chemical engineers are cranking out new paints and lacquers (notice that almost everything in our human world is covered by some sort of lacquer.)  Food chemists are working in genetics and flavorings.  Petroleum chemists are working on better cracking and new products.  The list goes on.

Importance is in the eye of the beholder.  Quantification of importance is impossible.  If you want to know what is deemed newsworthy by, e.g. the American Chemical Society, pick up the past issue of Chemical & Engineering news and take a look.

Comment: "You can't get a simple answer for this question." It's possible in every other field (Hilbert and others). Why not in Chemistry?

Comment: @LSA Chemisty is to e.g. "nanotechnology" as Mathematics is to e.g. "Hilbert space"  You are talking about a radically different scope.  Even within a subfield, there are different areas of focus.  I have some familiarity Hilbert (and Banach) spaces, and folks are working on all sorts of different problems even in those subdisciplines.

Comment: I was not talking about Hilbert spaces. I was saying that Hilbert was able to describe to describe the mathematics of the 20th century with his famous list (not perfectly of course, but not that far).

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure the person working on the 24th most important problem thought Hilbert was a complete idiot.

Comment: Another thing, you may ask a different question: "Is there a luminary in chemistry who has compiled a list of what he/she thinks are the most important problems in chemistry?"